# BeautifulSoup, extract a table (from poorly designed site) and turn it into a CSV

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying [to extract this table in whole](http://www.boxofficemojo.com/alltime/adjusted.htm) - any tips? I've tried the following code 8 different ways, with no avail. Thank you!

```
data = []
table = soup.find_all("tbody")
rows = table.find_all("tr")

for row in rows: 
    cols = row.find_all("td")
    cols = [ele.text.strip() for ele in cols]
    data.append([ele for ele in cols if ele])
```

Answer (score 1):

Code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = requests.get('http://www.boxofficemojo.com/alltime/adjusted.htm').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
table = soup.find('table', cellspacing='1')
f = open('data.csv','w')
for row in table.find_all('tr'):
    print(''.join(row.findAll(text=True)).replace('\n', '|'))
    f.write(''.join(row.findAll(text=True)).replace('\n', '|') + '\n')
f.close()
```

Output:

```
1|Gone with the Wind|MGM|$1,854,769,700|$198,676,459|1939^|
2|Star Wars|Fox|$1,635,137,900|$460,998,007|1977^|
3|The Sound of Music|Fox|$1,307,373,200|$158,671,368|1965|
4|E.T.: The Extra-Terrestrial|Uni.|$1,302,222,800|$435,110,554|1982^|
5|Titanic|Par.|$1,244,347,300|$659,363,944|1997^|
6|The Ten Commandments|Par.|$1,202,580,000|$65,500,000|1956|
7|Jaws|Uni.|$1,175,763,500|$260,000,000|1975|
8|Doctor Zhivago|MGM|$1,139,563,500|$111,721,910|1965|
9|The Exorcist|WB|$1,015,300,400|$232,906,145|1973^|
10|Snow White and the Seven Dwarfs|Dis.|$1,000,620,000|$184,925,486|1937^|
11|Star Wars: The Force Awakens|BV|$992,496,600|$936,662,225|2015|
12|101 Dalmatians|Dis.|$917,240,400|$144,880,014|1961^|
13|The Empire Strikes Back|Fox|$901,298,200|$290,475,067|1980^|
14|Ben-Hur|MGM|$899,640,000|$74,000,000|1959|
15|Avatar|Fox|$893,301,900|$760,507,625|2009^|
16|Return of the Jedi|Fox|$863,465,400|$309,306,177|1983^|
17|Jurassic Park|Uni.|$843,843,500|$402,453,882|1993^|
18|Star Wars: Episode I - The Phantom Menace|Fox|$829,064,800|$474,544,677|1999^|
19|The Lion King|BV|$818,364,200|$422,783,777|1994^|
20|The Sting|Uni.|$818,331,400|$156,000,000|1973|
21|Raiders of the Lost Ark|Par.|$812,675,900|$248,159,971|1981^|
22|The Graduate|AVCO|$785,595,300|$104,945,305|1967^|
23|Fantasia|Dis.|$762,339,100|$76,408,097|1941^|
24|Jurassic World|Uni.|$725,671,700|$652,270,625|2015|
25|The Godfather|Par.|$724,509,200|$134,966,411|1972^|
26|Forrest Gump|Par.|$721,682,300|$330,252,182|1994^|
27|Mary Poppins|Dis.|$717,709,100|$102,272,727|1964^|
28|Grease|Par.|$706,577,200|$188,755,690|1978^|
29|Marvel's The Avengers|BV|$705,769,500|$623,357,910|2012|
30|Thunderball|UA|$686,664,000|$63,595,658|1965|
31|The Dark Knight|WB|$683,575,000|$534,858,444|2008^|
32|The Jungle Book|Dis.|$676,381,600|$141,843,612|1967^|
33|Sleeping Beauty|Dis.|$667,166,200|$51,600,000|1959^|
34|Ghostbusters|Col.|$653,374,800|$242,212,467|1984^|
35|Shrek 2|DW|$652,247,500|$441,226,247|2004|
36|Butch Cassidy and the Sundance Kid|Fox|$647,721,100|$102,308,889|1969|
37|Love Story|Par.|$642,583,000|$106,397,186|1970|
38|Spider-Man|Sony|$637,870,000|$403,706,375|2002|
39|Independence Day|Fox|$635,888,300|$306,169,268|1996^|
40|Home Alone|Fox|$621,799,900|$285,761,243|1990|
41|Pinocchio|Dis.|$618,762,600|$84,254,167|1940^|
42|Cleopatra (1963)|Fox|$616,744,200|$57,777,778|1963|
43|Beverly Hills Cop|Par.|$616,437,200|$234,760,478|1984|
44|Star Wars: The Last Jedi|BV|$615,738,300|$615,738,279|2017|
45|Goldfinger|UA|$608,634,000|$51,081,062|1964|
46|Airport|Uni.|$606,901,600|$100,489,151|1970|
47|American Graffiti|Uni.|$603,257,100|$115,000,000|1973|
48|The Robe|Fox|$600,872,700|$36,000,000|1953|
49|Pirates of the Caribbean: Dead Man's Chest|BV|$593,288,400|$423,315,812|2006|
50|Around the World in 80 Days|UA|$593,169,200|$42,000,000|1956|
51|Bambi|RKO|$584,880,300|$102,247,150|1942^|
52|Blazing Saddles|WB|$580,539,700|$119,601,481|1974^|
53|Batman|WB|$577,923,400|$251,188,924|1989|
54|The Bells of St. Mary's|RKO|$576,000,000|$21,333,333|1945|
55|The Lord of the Rings: The Return of the King|NL|$565,852,400|$377,845,905|2003^|
56|Finding Nemo|BV|$565,364,200|$380,843,261|2003^|
57|The Towering Inferno|Fox|$563,428,600|$116,000,000|1974|
58|Rogue One: A Star Wars Story|BV|$554,854,100|$532,177,324|2016|
59|Cinderella (1950)|Dis.|$553,567,100|$93,141,149|1950^|
60|Spider-Man 2|Sony|$552,257,300|$373,585,825|2004|
61|My Fair Lady|WB|$550,800,000|$72,000,000|1964|
62|The Greatest Show on Earth|Par.|$550,800,000|$36,000,000|1952|
63|National Lampoon's Animal House|Uni.|$549,792,700|$141,600,000|1978^|
64|The Passion of the Christ|NM|$548,090,400|$370,782,930|2004^|
65|Star Wars: Episode III - Revenge of the Sith|Fox|$544,599,700|$380,270,577|2005^|
66|Back to the Future|Uni.|$542,085,000|$210,609,762|1985|
67|The Lord of the Rings: The Two Towers|NL|$529,918,100|$342,551,365|2002^|
68|The Dark Knight Rises|WB|$528,601,000|$448,139,099|2012|
69|The Sixth Sense|BV|$528,576,400|$293,506,292|1999|
70|Superman|WB|$526,547,600|$134,218,018|1978|
71|Tootsie|Col.|$522,378,200|$177,200,000|1982|
72|Smokey and the Bandit|Uni.|$521,726,300|$126,737,428|1977|
73|Beauty and the Beast (2017)|BV|$521,407,600|$504,014,165|2017|
74|Finding Dory|BV|$515,531,300|$486,295,561|2016|
75|West Side Story|MGM|$513,807,200|$43,656,822|1961|
76|Close Encounters of the Third Kind|Col.|$513,370,800|$135,189,114|1977^|
77|Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone|WB|$513,281,200|$317,575,550|2001|
78|Lady and the Tramp|Dis.|$511,646,200|$93,602,326|1955^|
79|Lawrence of Arabia|Col.|$508,421,000|$44,824,144|1962^|
80|The Rocky Horror Picture Show|Fox|$505,537,300|$112,892,319|1975|
81|Rocky|UA|$505,267,000|$117,235,147|1976|
82|The Best Years of Our Lives|RKO|$504,900,000|$23,650,000|1946|
83|The Poseidon Adventure|Fox|$504,000,000|$84,563,118|1972|
84|The Lord of the Rings: The Fellowship of the Ring|NL|$503,057,400|$315,544,750|2001^|
85|Twister|WB|$502,037,000|$241,721,524|1996|
86|Men in Black|Sony|$501,381,100|$250,690,539|1997|
87|The Bridge on the River Kwai|Col.|$499,392,000|$27,200,000|1957|
88|Transformers: Revenge of the Fallen|P/DW|$494,810,500|$402,111,870|2009|
89|It's a Mad, Mad, Mad, Mad World|MGM|$494,576,300|$46,332,858|1963|
90|Swiss Family Robinson|Dis.|$493,957,400|$40,356,000|1960|
91|One Flew Over the Cuckoo's Nest|UA|$492,831,600|$108,981,275|1975|
92|M.A.S.H.|Fox|$492,821,000|$81,600,000|1970|
93|Indiana Jones and the Temple of Doom|Par.|$491,431,300|$179,870,271|1984|
94|Avengers: Age of Ultron|BV|$491,377,100|$459,005,868|2015|
95|Star Wars: Episode II - Attack of the Clones|Fox|$490,840,600|$310,676,740|2002^|
96|Toy Story 3|BV|$489,656,000|$415,004,880|2010|
97|Mrs. Doubtfire|Fox|$483,642,600|$219,195,243|1993|
98|Aladdin|BV|$481,420,700|$217,350,219|1992|
99|Ghost|Par.|$472,450,700|$217,631,306|1990|
100|The Hunger Games: Catching Fire|LGF|$469,232,400|$424,668,047|2013|
101|Duel in the Sun|Selz.|$468,367,300|$20,408,163|1946|
102|The Hunger Games|LGF|$466,924,700|$408,010,692|2012|
103|Pirates of the Caribbean: The Curse of the Black Pearl|BV|$464,956,900|$305,413,918|2003|
104|House of Wax|WB|$463,883,000|$23,750,000|1953|
105|Rear Window|Par.|$462,256,500|$36,764,313|1954^|
106|The Lost World: Jurassic Park|Uni.|$458,173,400|$229,086,679|1997|
107|Indiana Jones and the Last Crusade|Par.|$453,643,400|$197,171,806|1989|
108|Monsters, Inc.|BV|$453,061,600|$289,916,256|2001^|
109|Frozen|BV|$450,196,500|$400,738,009|2013|
110|Spider-Man 3|Sony|$449,033,200|$336,530,303|2007|
111|Iron Man 3|BV|$448,060,700|$409,013,994|2013|
112|Terminator 2: Judgment Day|TriS|$447,732,400|$205,881,154|1991^|
113|Sergeant York|WB|$441,770,900|$16,361,885|1941|
114|How the Grinch Stole Christmas|Uni.|$441,620,600|$260,044,825|2000|
115|Top Gun|Par.|$440,917,900|$179,800,601|1986^|
116|Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows Part 2|WB|$440,547,300|$381,011,219|2011|
117|Toy Story 2|BV|$439,139,300|$245,852,179|1999^|
118|Shrek|DW|$434,128,000|$267,665,011|2001|
119|Shrek the Third|P/DW|$430,606,000|$322,719,944|2007|
120|Despicable Me 2|Uni.|$430,487,800|$368,061,265|2013|
121|Captain America: Civil War|BV|$429,213,000|$408,084,349|2016|
122|The Matrix Reloaded|WB|$428,668,600|$281,576,461|2003|
123|Transformers|P/DW|$425,970,900|$319,246,193|2007|
124|Crocodile Dundee|Par.|$424,138,600|$174,803,506|1986|
125|Wonder Woman|WB|$423,340,500|$412,563,408|2017|
126|The Four Horsemen of the Apocalypse|MPC|$421,530,600|$9,183,673|1921|
127|Saving Private Ryan|DW|$419,958,100|$216,540,909|1998|
128|Young Frankenstein|Fox|$419,041,900|$86,273,333|1974|
129|Peter Pan|Dis.|$418,824,000|$87,404,651|1953^|
130|Gremlins|WB|$417,526,300|$153,083,102|1984^|
131|Beauty and the Beast|BV|$416,438,900|$218,967,620|1991^|
132|The Chronicles of Narnia: The Lion, the Witch and the Wardrobe|BV|$414,717,600|$291,710,957|2005|
133|Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire|WB|$414,709,000|$290,013,036|2005|
134|Pirates of the Caribbean: At World's End|BV|$412,860,400|$309,420,425|2007|
135|Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets|WB|$412,327,800|$261,988,482|2002|
136|The Fugitive|WB|$407,567,300|$183,875,760|1993|
137|The Caine Mutiny|Col.|$407,479,600|$21,750,000|1954|
138|Iron Man|Par.|$407,095,000|$318,412,101|2008|
139|Transformers: Dark of the Moon|P/DW|$406,315,000|$352,390,543|2011|
140|Meet the Fockers|Uni.|$405,508,300|$279,261,160|2004|
141|Indiana Jones and the Kingdom of the Crystal Skull|Par.|$405,430,100|$317,101,119|2008|
142|Toy Story|BV|$402,711,200|$191,796,233|1995^|
143|Dances with Wolves|Orion|$401,159,500|$184,208,848|1990|
144|An Officer and a Gentleman|Par.|$400,769,900|$129,795,554|1982|
145|Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 2|BV|$399,848,900|$389,813,101|2017|
146|2001: A Space Odyssey|MGM|$397,829,200|$56,954,992|1968^|
147|Rain Man|MGM|$397,417,800|$172,825,435|1988|
148|The Secret Life of Pets|Uni.|$397,253,600|$368,384,330|2016|
149|Guess Who's Coming to Dinner|Col.|$397,099,200|$56,666,667|1967|
150|Inside Out|BV|$396,452,900|$356,461,711|2015|
151|American Sniper|WB|$395,474,400|$350,126,372|2014|
152|Kramer Vs. Kramer|Col.|$394,925,800|$106,260,000|1979|
153|Armageddon|BV|$394,560,300|$201,578,182|1998|
154|Psycho|Uni.|$391,680,100|$32,000,000|1960|
155|Rocky III|UA|$390,271,700|$125,049,125|1982^|
156|Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix|WB|$389,622,600|$292,004,738|2007|
157|Rambo: First Blood Part II|TriS|$388,961,600|$150,415,432|1985|
158|Batman Forever|WB|$388,369,100|$184,031,112|1995|
159|Deadpool|Fox|$388,249,600|$363,070,709|2016|
160|Pretty Woman|BV|$387,179,600|$178,406,268|1990|
161|Earthquake|Uni.|$386,952,300|$79,666,653|1974|
162|Alice in Wonderland (2010)|BV|$385,896,200|$334,191,110|2010|
163|The Incredibles|BV|$385,835,000|$261,441,092|2004|
164|Cast Away|Fox|$384,588,700|$233,632,142|2000|
165|Home Alone 2: Lost in New York|Fox|$384,179,200|$173,585,516|1992|
166|The Jungle Book (2016)|BV|$382,904,500|$364,001,123|2016|
167|Three Men and a Baby|BV|$382,840,700|$167,780,960|1987|
168|My Big Fat Greek Wedding|IFC|$380,230,800|$241,438,208|2002|
169|Guardians of the Galaxy|BV|$378,010,100|$333,176,600|2014|
170|Furious 7|Uni.|$376,598,400|$353,007,020|2015|
171|Mission: Impossible|Par.|$375,885,400|$180,981,856|1996|
172|The Hunger Games: Mockingjay - Part 1|LGF|$373,872,900|$337,135,885|2014|
173|Minions|Uni.|$373,756,800|$336,045,770|2015|
174|Saturday Night Fever|Par.|$372,751,500|$94,213,184|1977|
175|On Golden Pond|Uni.|$372,564,100|$119,285,432|1981|
176|Austin Powers: The Spy Who Shagged Me|NL|$372,332,300|$206,040,086|1999|
177|Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince|WB|$371,524,900|$301,959,197|2009|
178|Bruce Almighty|Uni.|$369,680,400|$242,829,261|2003|
179|Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban|WB|$368,886,800|$249,541,069|2004|
180|Funny Girl|Col.|$367,562,200|$52,223,306|1968^|
181|Mission: Impossible II|Par.|$366,876,200|$215,409,889|2000|
182|Rush Hour 2|NL|$366,817,700|$226,164,286|2001|
183|Apollo 13|Uni.|$365,894,000|$173,837,933|1995^|
184|Patton|Fox|$365,718,000|$61,749,765|1970|
185|Fatal Attraction|Par.|$364,269,300|$156,645,693|1987|
186|Zootopia|BV|$363,584,000|$341,268,248|2016|
187|Liar Liar|Uni.|$362,821,200|$181,410,615|1997|
188|Robin Hood: Prince of Thieves|WB|$360,863,200|$165,493,908|1991|
189|Beverly Hills Cop II|Par.|$360,778,800|$153,665,036|1987|
190|Iron Man 2|Par.|$360,772,100|$312,433,331|2010|
191|Up|BV|$360,533,300|$293,004,164|2009|
192|Batman Returns|WB|$360,191,600|$162,831,698|1992|
193|Signs|BV|$360,164,800|$227,966,634|2002|
194|Jumanji: Welcome to the Jungle|Sony|$358,036,900|$358,036,871|2017|
195|The Twilight Saga: Eclipse|Sum.|$357,823,200|$300,531,751|2010|
196|Superman II|WB|$357,246,300|$108,185,706|1981|
197|The Twilight Saga: New Moon|Sum.|$357,194,500|$296,623,634|2009|
198|What's Up, Doc?|WB|$356,400,000|$66,000,000|1972|
199|9 to 5|Fox|$352,493,200|$103,290,500|1980|
200|Batman v Superman: Dawn of Justice|WB|$351,232,600|$330,360,194|2016|
201|The Firm|Par.|$351,120,300|$158,348,367|1993|
202|Suicide Squad|WB|$350,483,800|$325,100,054|2016|
203|Who Framed Roger Rabbit|BV|$349,448,400|$156,452,370|1988|
204|Inception|WB|$348,133,400|$292,576,195|2010|
205|Skyfall|Sony|$347,389,600|$304,360,277|2012|
206|The Hobbit: An Unexpected Journey|WB (NL)|$347,313,400|$303,003,568|2012|
207|Porky's|Fox|$346,289,600|$111,289,673|1982^|
208|Air Force One|Sony|$345,835,200|$172,956,409|1997|
209|Stir Crazy|Col.|$345,700,400|$101,300,000|1980|
210|A Star Is Born (1976)|WB|$344,788,700|$80,000,000|1976|
211|There's Something About Mary|Fox|$344,053,800|$176,484,651|1998|
212|Spider-Man: Homecoming|Sony|$343,499,000|$334,201,140|2017|
213|Cars|BV|$342,088,800|$244,082,982|2006|
214|The Hangover|WB|$341,182,900|$277,322,503|2009|
215|Lethal Weapon 2|WB|$340,501,700|$147,253,986|1989|
216|Night at the Museum|Fox|$340,041,900|$250,863,268|2006|
217|Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows Part 1|WB|$339,560,700|$295,983,305|2010|
218|I Am Legend|WB|$337,126,200|$256,393,010|2007|
219|Austin Powers in Goldmember|NL|$337,033,800|$213,307,889|2002|
220|War of the Worlds|Par.|$335,521,600|$234,280,354|2005|
221|It|WB (NL)|$335,148,900|$327,481,748|2017|
222|Every Which Way But Loose|WB|$334,232,400|$85,196,485|1978|
223|The Twilight Saga: Breaking Dawn Part 2|LG/S|$333,495,700|$292,324,737|2012|
224|The Love Bug|Dis.|$331,410,900|$51,264,000|1969|
225|The Twilight Saga: Breaking Dawn Part 1|Sum.|$329,680,800|$281,287,133|2011|
226|You Only Live Twice|UA|$329,598,600|$43,084,787|1967|
227|X-Men: The Last Stand|Fox|$328,465,300|$234,362,462|2006|
228|The Mummy Returns|Uni.|$327,657,500|$202,019,785|2001|
229|X2: X-Men United|Fox|$327,236,800|$214,949,694|2003|
230|Platoon|Orion|$325,302,500|$138,530,565|1986|
231|Rocky IV|UA|$324,855,400|$127,873,716|1985|
232|Pearl Harbor|BV|$322,017,800|$198,542,554|2001|
233|True Lies|Fox|$321,261,400|$146,282,411|1994|
234|Heaven Can Wait (1978)|Par.|$320,281,100|$81,640,278|1978|
235|Lethal Weapon 3|WB|$320,153,100|$144,731,527|1992|
236|Look Who's Talking|TriS|$319,854,500|$140,088,813|1989|
237|Gladiator|DW|$319,592,900|$187,705,427|2000|
238|Man of Steel|WB|$318,830,300|$291,045,518|2013|
239|Jaws 2|Uni.|$318,717,900|$81,766,007|1978^|
240|Star Trek|Par.|$317,150,800|$257,730,019|2009|
241|The Santa Clause|BV|$316,776,400|$144,833,357|1994|
242|The Amityville Horror|AIP|$316,113,900|$86,432,000|1979|
243|Thor: Ragnarok|BV|$314,143,200|$314,143,225|2017|
244|The Waterboy|BV|$314,053,600|$161,491,646|1998|
245|A Bug's Life|BV|$313,363,900|$162,798,565|1998|
246|A Few Good Men|Col.|$313,069,200|$141,340,178|1992|
247|The Odd Couple|Par.|$312,030,500|$44,527,234|1968|
248|Rocky II|UA|$311,542,700|$85,182,160|1979|
249|Jerry Maguire|Sony|$311,468,800|$153,952,592|1996|
250|The Perfect Storm|WB|$311,027,300|$182,618,434|2000|
251|King Kong|Uni.|$310,014,100|$218,080,025|2005|
252|The Matrix|WB|$309,879,100|$171,479,930|1999|
253|The Amazing Spider-Man|Sony|$309,163,500|$262,030,663|2012|
254|Tarzan|BV|$309,122,000|$171,091,819|1999|
255|Sister Act|BV|$308,813,300|$139,605,150|1992|
256|Hooper|WB|$306,000,000|$78,000,000|1978|
257|The Blind Side|WB|$305,701,600|$255,959,475|2009|
258|The Da Vinci Code|Sony|$304,882,700|$217,536,138|2006|
259|Monsters University|BV|$304,779,900|$268,492,764|2013|
260|All the President's Men|WB|$304,276,100|$70,600,000|1976|
261|What Women Want|Par.|$303,763,400|$182,811,707|2000|
262|The Bourne Ultimatum|Uni.|$303,515,200|$227,471,070|2007|
263|Gravity|WB|$302,369,300|$274,092,705|2013|
264|Honey, I Shrunk the Kids|BV|$302,279,100|$130,724,172|1989|
265|Terms of Endearment|Par.|$301,824,600|$108,423,489|1983|
266|Men in Black II|Sony|$300,868,300|$190,418,803|2002|
267|Star Trek: The Motion Picture|Par.|$300,849,700|$82,258,456|1979|
268|Wedding Crashers|NL|$299,683,200|$209,255,921|2005|
269|Despicable Me|Uni.|$299,217,100|$251,513,985|2010|
270|Pocahontas|BV|$298,782,100|$141,579,773|1995|
271|Arthur|WB|$298,725,900|$95,461,682|1981|
272|The Hunger Games: Mockingjay - Part 2|LGF|$297,446,700|$281,723,902|2015|
273|The LEGO Movie|WB|$296,654,200|$257,760,692|2014|
274|Batman Begins|WB|$295,860,600|$206,852,432|2005^|
275|Apocalypse Now|MGM|$295,789,400|$83,471,511|1979^|
276|Charlie and the Chocolate Factory|WB|$295,677,800|$206,459,076|2005|
277|Big Daddy|Sony|$295,422,100|$163,479,795|1999|
278|Ocean's Eleven|WB|$294,446,200|$183,417,150|2001|
279|Jurassic Park III|Uni.|$293,844,100|$181,171,875|2001|
280|Teenage Mutant Ninja Turtles|NL|$293,555,800|$135,265,915|1990|
281|Planet of the Apes (2001)|Fox|$291,948,200|$180,011,740|2001|
282|Alien|Fox|$291,755,600|$80,931,801|1979^|
283|Hancock|Sony|$291,441,100|$227,946,274|2008|
284|As Good as It Gets|Sony|$290,776,100|$148,478,011|1997|
285|The Hangover Part II|WB|$289,972,400|$254,464,305|2011|
286|Midnight Cowboy|UA|$289,525,900|$44,785,053|1969|
287|The Hobbit: The Desolation of Smaug|WB (NL)|$289,308,500|$258,366,855|2013|
288|The French Connection|Fox|$287,640,000|$51,700,000|1971|
289|The Flintstones|Uni.|$286,669,000|$130,531,208|1994|
290|Captain America: The Winter Soldier|BV|$286,373,800|$259,766,572|2014|
291|Coming to America|Par.|$286,238,000|$128,152,301|1988|
292|National Treasure: Book of Secrets|BV|$286,164,000|$219,964,115|2007|
293|WALL-E|BV|$286,150,300|$223,808,164|2008|
294|The Hobbit: The Battle of the Five Armies|WB (NL)|$285,304,300|$255,119,788|2014|
295|The Silence of the Lambs|Orion|$285,087,900|$130,742,922|1991|
296|The Karate Kid Part II|Col.|$284,812,500|$115,103,979|1986|
297|Airplane!|Par.|$284,796,800|$83,453,539|1980|
298|Alvin and the Chipmunks|Fox|$284,128,700|$217,326,974|2007|
299|Meet the Parents|Uni.|$282,676,300|$166,244,045|2000|
300|Ransom|BV|$282,366,800|$136,492,681|1996|
```

Comment: Awesome! Is there a way to turn this into a dictionary and/or csv in the loop? I was able to get a similar answer using beautiful soup and bleach, but I'm stuck in a string...

Comment: I just updated my code, please edit your question to include the requested csv functionality.